# How can I run batch in a shell?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, elixir, elixir-iex

I want to have a batch file that opens the command prompt, launches the iex shell within it and then starts my elixir program. The issue I'm having is that as soon as I invoke iex -S mix, which compiles the code and opens the elixir shell, then I am unable to write more commands into it.

```
:: Start iex and compile with mix
iex -S mix

:: Start elevators 
Elevator.Supervisor.start

pause
```

[image]

The last part `Elevator.Supervisor.start` never runs, for some reason. I guess this is because I opened a shell within the command prompt. Is there a way to feed commands into the iex?

Comment: u need to pipe input into the iex?

Comment: @HackingAddict0302 `iex` won’t accept any piping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***TL;DR* use `.iex.exs` file which is loaded by `iex` upon start.**

---

- Create a file named `.iex.exs` in the project directory root with the content you want to be run:

```rb
    Elevator.Supervisor.start()
```

- remove any reference to [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) code (which is now located in `.iex.exs`) from your `.bat` file
- run `.bat` file
- enjoy.

Comment: **`.iex.exs` file is loaded by `iex` upon start** as I stated in the very first line of the answer.

Comment: I got it now. My .iex.exs was in a folder above the one running iex. Thank you.